# How can I style acceptance label in contact form 7?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm working on a wordpress site with Contact Form 7 plugin. 
When you click on "registrace" button, you can crearly see, that I can't style the "I accept" button and text.
I would like to center them and have some decent margin.
Web: https://wattax.eu?
Can you please help me, to style them?
Thanks in advance

I've already tried several Additional CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
p:not(.has-background):last-of-type {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

For the checkbox use this:

```
.wpcf7 input, .wpcf7 textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this rule line 22215:

```css
#wpcf7-f219-p47-o1 > form > p:nth-child(34) {
  display: flex;
}
```

replace with:

```css
.inputter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.inputter .wpcf7-list-item {
  margin-right: 1.2%;
}

.inputter input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px
}
```

and change p html (first after 'Nadpis') to:

```html
<p class="inputter">
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap acceptance-236">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-acceptance optional">
      <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="acceptance-236" value="1" aria-invalid="false">
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
  I accept
</p>
```

also a side note requiered should be 'required' in case you missed it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to @myselfmiqdad for prettifying my hastily typed code :)